# A mix of c++ and cublas code isn't compiling

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc, cublas

So I have this code that's suppose to compute the dot product of a matrix in different ways (one of which is to use blas in a c++), but when I try to use nvcc to compile the code, it doesn't work and it says that I have an undefined reference to ddot. This is weird because I'm pretty sure I'm using the calling notation referenced here for cublas: http://www.sdsc.edu/us/training/assets/docs/NVIDIA-03-Toolkit.pdf

Can anyone help me? Here's a snip of code I'm having trouble with:

```
#include <cublas.h> //just some included files here. No problems with these
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" //This is where I mention the cublas functions are external.
//I think this is necessary since I also have cuda pieces of code
{
    double cublasDDOT_(int *n, double *A, int *incA, double *B, int *incB);

    void cublasDAXPY_(int *n, double *a, double *A, int *incA, double *B, int *incB);
}

//Stuff happens here

C[i][t]=cublasDDOT_(&n, partA, &incA, partB, &incB); //This is a piece of my function and where the compiler chokes up
```

This is weird to me. I've also tried removing the "_"'s with no luck.

Here's the compile command I use: `nvcc program`

Do I need to mention the cublas library during the compile somehow? I have the cuda toolkit installed, but I don't know how to reference the library other than with

`#include <cublas.h>`

**New update**

It turns out I get the same output whether I include the cublas.h header or not

I also get the same output whether I type -lcublas or not

Here's the output, which is garbage for all compiles (with/without cublas.h & with/without -lcublas)

```
nvcc project4.cu -lcublas
/tmp/tmpxft_000051cb_00000000-14_project4.o: In function `ddot(int&, int&, int&, double**&, double**&, double**&, double*&, double*&, int&, int&, double&, double&, double*)':
tmpxft_000051cb_00000000-3_project4.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xda1): undefined reference to `cublasDDOT'
/tmp/tmpxft_000051cb_00000000-14_project4.o: In function `daxpy(int&, int&, int&, double**&, double**&, double**&, double**&, double*&, double*&, int&, int&, double&, double&, double*)':
tmpxft_000051cb_00000000-3_project4.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xff3): undefined reference to `cublasDAXPY'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Do you have to tread cublasDDOT as "C" outside of "extern C" ?

Comment: @huseyin tugrul buyukisik What do you mean? I don't understand. I do use cublasDDOT in my c code though.

Comment: Maybe declaring one of the read-only parameters as const could help. Maybe not.  Maybe __restrict__ helps.

Comment: What is **restrict**?

Comment: Something about non-overlapping of parameters in memory space. What is your CUDA device by the way?

Comment: I'm not sure since it's on a server called redhawk. All I know is that I have a cuda toolkit module that I've loaded and it seems to accept cudablas.h in the include. It's just it doesn't recognize ddot and daxpy, and I have no idea why. Cudablas should recognize those, right?

Comment: I know too few. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when compiling with nvcc, you still need to specify the `-lcublas` link switch.

It looks like you're calling out the function names incorrectly:

```
cublasDDOT_()
```

should be:

```
cublasDdot()
```

and:

```
cublasDAXPY_()
```

should be:

```
cublasDaxpy()
```

The naming is case-sensitive.

If you're not sure about the correct naming, refer to the cublas [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html) and take a look at the usage in the [sample codes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cudalibraries)

And yes, remove the underscores.  I don't understand why you're calling the function names that way.  If you mangle a name, there's no way the linker knows what you intend to link it to.

I'm also not sure any of the "extern C" stuff is necessary.  That depends on what else is going on in your project, but I don't think you should use "extern C" wrapped around functions that you intend to be linked with the cublas library, if you are compiling/linking with nvcc

Comment: I can't do the link thing since it's on a weird server with unknown paths. I think it's linked right though since -lcublas is accepted, right?

Comment: Oh, that's funny, I get the same output whether I use -lcublas or not

Comment: Yes, I also missed that you seem to be using incorrect function names, I edited my answer above.

Comment: Ha ha! well done! I just figured this out and was about to post the answer when I saw your post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you use new with the nvcc compiler instead of malloc? The reason I ask is because it compiles now, but my code is broken and returns 0 for the matrix mult. Before, when compiling with g++, it worked fine. I know this is a weird question since I think nvcc uses g++, but I figured it was worth asking.

Comment: Yes, you can use `new` with nvcc.  You are correct that host code gets passed off to the host compiler.

Comment: you can't use -lcublas for operations that aren't on the GPU can you?